# Circular dependency headache

Tags: c++, header, linker, circular-dependency

**The initial question was**
I have three classes `A`, `B` and `C`. `A` has a link and calls to `B`, which has a link and calls to `C`. But `C` has a call to `A` static method. And I just can't get this static call to work.

**But guys cought me on some inaccuracy in truncating the code, so the real names of the classes are** `GameRenderer`, `GameView` and `FieldView`. `GameRenderer` has a link and calls to `GameView`, which has a link and calls to `FieldView`. But `FieldView` has a call to `GameRenderer` static method `createGlTextureFromResource`. And I just can't get this static call to work.

Here is the full and real headers
GameRenderer.h

```
// GameRenderer.h
#ifndef GAME_RENDERER
#define GAME_RENDERER

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>

namespace game{
    class GameModel;
    class GameView;

    class GameRenderer {
            jobject*    context;
            jobject*    gameOverHandler;
            static JNIEnv*     env;
            static jobject*    jparent;

            GameModel*  gameModel;
            GameView*   gameView;

            glm::mat4 mProjMatrix;
            glm::mat4 mVMatrix;

        public:
            GameRenderer(jobject* context, jobject* gameOverHandler, JNIEnv* env, jobject* jparent);

            void onSurfaceCreated();
            void onDrawFrame();
            void onSurfaceChanged(int width, int height);
            void setMotionDirection();

            static int* getImagePixels (int imageId, int width, int height);
            static void createGlTextureFromResource (int resourceId, int textureId);
    };
}

#endif
```

GameView.h

```
// GameView.h
#ifndef GAME_VIEW
#define GAME_VIEW

#include <glm/glm.hpp>

namespace game{
    class GameModel;
    class FieldView;

    class GameView {
        GameModel* gameModel;

        FieldView* fieldView;
        public:
        GameView(GameModel* gameModel);
        void draw(glm::mat4 mProjMatrix, glm::mat4 mVMatrix);
    };
}

#endif
```

FieldView.h

```
// FieldView.h
#ifndef FIELD_VIEW
#define FIELD_VIEW

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>

#include "GLESUtils.h"

namespace game{
    class GameRenderer;

    class FieldView {
        static const int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
        static const int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
        static const int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
        static const int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;

        glm::mat4 mMMatrix;
        glm::mat4 mMVPMatrix;

        int mProgram;
        int mTextureID;
        int muMVPMatrixHandle;
        int maPositionHandle;
        int maTextureHandle;

        public:
        FieldView();
        void draw(glm::mat4 mProjMatrix, glm::mat4 mVMatrix);
    };
}

#endif
```

here is cut version of FieldView.cpp

```
// FieldView.cpp
#include <jni.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <android/log.h>  

#include "FieldView.h"
#include "GameRenderer.h"

#define  LOG_TAG    "NDK_FieldView"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

namespace game{
    static GLfloat mTriangleVerticesData[] = {...};

    static const char mVertexShader[] = "...\n";

    static const char mFragmentShader[] = "...\n";

    FieldView::FieldView() {
        mProgram            = -1;
        mTextureID          = -1;
        muMVPMatrixHandle   = -1;
        maPositionHandle    = -1;
        maTextureHandle     = -1;

        mProgram = GLESUtils::createProgram(mVertexShader, mFragmentShader);
        GLESUtils::checkGlError("createProgram mProgram");
        if (mProgram == 0) {
            LOGI("program not created exiting");
            return;
        }
        maPositionHandle = glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
        GLESUtils::checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
        if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
            return;
        }
        maTextureHandle = glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
        GLESUtils::checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
        if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
            return;
        }

        muMVPMatrixHandle = glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        GLESUtils::checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
        if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
            return;
        }

        /*
         * Create our texture. This has to be done each time the
         * surface is created.
         */

        GLuint textures[] = {0};
        glGenTextures(1, &textures[0]);

        mTextureID = textures[0];
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureID);

        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        // here is the actual problem, I get the following error on this line
        // FieldView.cpp: In constructor 'game::FieldView::FieldView()':
        // FieldView.cpp:89:9: error: incomplete type 'game::GameRenderer' used in nested name specifier

        GameRenderer::createGlTextureFromResource(0x7f040004, mTextureID);
    }

    void FieldView::draw(glm::mat4 mProjMatrix, glm::mat4 mVMatrix) {
        //... doesn't matter
    }
}
```

If I understand right, I have to use forward declarations and don't use includes of headers at least in one place to brake the circle, but I can't do this because I have calls between objects, and without headers compiler refuses to do calls to methods. **The compiler error** is in the `FieldView.cpp`, see comments in the code near the `GameRenderer::createGlTextureFromResource(0x7f040004, mTextureID);` call.

**After all these edits** questions actually stays the same:
What am I doing wrong here? I suppose I'm using very bad design practice somewhere.

Please forgive my initial inaccuracy.

Comment: I don't quite get the problem. Why aren't you including the other headers as well? On the other hand, I missed your includes at the end of the files :-(

Comment: I included headers in header files, so I get the inevident overlapping of the names in the `C` a.k.a `FieldView`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should work:

- Stop including headers from other headers. You don't need them, which is clear from the fact that it's only included as the last line. As a general rule, include as little as possible in headers and try to get away with simple declarations (such as `class B;`) whenever possible.
- Include both `A.h` and `C.h` from `C.cpp`. Both classes are used directly from `C.cpp`, therefore it makes sense that you need to include both headers.

Comment: hmm, I tried this but it had no effect, compiler says the same error... and logically I don't see much difference.

Comment: There was a mistake in include guards in other module... the name of the guard coincided with GameRenderer... and I found it when started to change the model of header include file by file, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason, at least in the code you posted, to include `B.h` at the bottom of `A.h` and so on. You should put these includes in the implementation files.

```
// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
namespace game
{
 ....
}
```

Comment: this didn't change anything, I'm still getting the `FieldView.cpp
C.cpp: In constructor 'game::C::C()':
C.cpp:89:9: error: incomplete type 'game::A' used in nested name specifier`

Comment: @AntonBoritskiy that doesn't help much, since your example doesn't have anything called `FieldView`. Could you post a representative example?

Comment: @AntonBoritskiy I'm confused. As my answer states, if you change `C(jobject* context);` to `C();` (since your default constructor in C.cpp needs a declaration) it compiles for me. Are you actually testing the code you have given here or is this just supposed to represent the code you're actually using?

Comment: @AntonBoritskiy - the error message says the problem is at line 89 in C.cpp, The C.cpp that is provided above has only 11 lines. What happens when you compile the posted code?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was inaccurate in translating names, see updated question for full sources

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the #include "A.h" is buying you nothing in the C.h header file. Your C.cpp header should include A.h and C.h.  Likewise, the B.h is including C.h at the tail as well, and just like before, buys you nothing.

```
A.h - include no other headers, forward decl class C;
B.h - include no other headers, forward decl class C;
C.h - include no other headers, forward decl class A

A.cpp - include A.h, C.h
B.cpp - include A.h, B.h, C.h
C.cpp - include A.h, C.h
```

It appears you have a mantra of only including one custom-header for a .cpp file. This is almost never the case with multi-class/multi-header hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles for me. Albeit by changing your constructor in C to be a default constructor (so the code in C.cpp has a declaration).